AVolute::GetProductInfoT - Error 20 - has not been implemented yet - where is it beeing called from? (Qt 6.8.0)
I am seeing these errors when running a simple Qt Application:
Error 20 (this feature has not been implemented yet) in function AVolute::GetProductInfoT::<lambda_3920e95365a48b95dd51020986e9e351>::operator ()
Error 20 (this feature has not been implemented yet) in function AVolute::GetProductInfoT::<lambda_3920e95365a48b95dd51020986e9e351>::operator ()
Error 20 (this feature has not been implemented yet) in function AVolute::GetProductInfoT::<lambda_3920e95365a48b95dd51020986e9e351>::operator ()
Error 20 (this feature has not been implemented yet) in function AVolute::GetProductInfoT::<lambda_3920e95365a48b95dd51020986e9e351>::operator ()
Error 20 (this feature has not been implemented yet) in function AVolute::GetProductInfoT::<lambda_3920e95365a48b95dd51020986e9e351>::operator ()
Error 20 (this feature has not been implemented yet) in function AVolute::GetProductInfoT::<lambda_3920e95365a48b95dd51020986e9e351>::operator ()
Error 20 (this feature has not been implemented yet) in function AVolute::GetProductInfoT::<lambda_3920e95365a48b95dd51020986e9e351>::operator ()

This does not seem to affect functionality in any way, but I am curious why is it called and from where. I never included his symbol. Running my main() step by step, most of the loglines come simply from initializing QApplication:
// logs the error 6 times
QApplication a(argc, argv);

I would like to know the cause of this. It is basically just annoying, but could be a symptom of bad setup. I'd like to silence or fix these if possible. This is probably Qt version specific and I'm using Qt 6.8.0 with MinGW64 on Windows 11.

QTBUG-79799 - "Deinstalling the "msi sonic radar" software seems to get rid of the problem" - Perhaps you have a similar issue?

I don't have that installed. But I do have MSI audio drivers. I kinda need those for obvious reasons. It makes sense though, I installed them in the last month and didn't see this message before when working on this project.

Come to think of it, I've got an MSI MB myself but I only have QT installed in my WSL2 environment. I don't get those outputs though.

A-Volute is Sonic Studio virtual mixer. Sounds either like bad driver or issue with preventing user-space software to identify hardware - a new Windows trend of false anti-tracking security
